# what is the properties of the REST service difference from others

Tags: php, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to learn technical properties of a REST service. BUt I should ask my questions confused me.

For example I create a php or .net web api page that works with JSON objects.

- http://myservice.com/products   (GET)
- http://myservice.com/products/get/1  (GET)
- http://myservice.com/products/create (POST)
- http://myservice.com/products/delete (POST)

Is this a rest service?

And looked at REST samples that has a single endpoint and that gets all HTTP methods.

- http://myservice.com/products (GET)
- http://myservice.com/products (POST)
- http://myservice.com/products (PUT)
- http://myservice.com/products (DELETE)

what is the rest specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

A rest service should work with xml, not JSON objects.

The whole topic is pretty wide, I will suggest to you to look at this short book about the difference between REST and API.

http://www.restapitutorial.com/media/RESTful_Best_Practices-v1_1.pdf